# I want to print out the text with the most number of times entered

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char str[100];
    int h[26]={0};
    int i, j, count, tmp=0;
    scanf("%s", str);
    count=strlen(str);
    for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
        h[str[i]-97]++;
    }
    for(j=0; j<25; j++) {
        if(h[j]<h[j+1]) {
            tmp=j+1;
        }
    }
    printf("%c", (char)tmp+97);
}
```

I want to output the most frequently entered lowercase letters, but how can I change it by output the strange values?

Try input this code "aaaabbbbsefa", then the "s" will be output.

Comment: Your code finds the array index of the alphabet (except 'z') which has a lesser occurrence than the next letter of the alphabet, adds 1 and converts that to the character that was next. So after 's' none has a lesser occurrence than the next, and 's' was reported. So have a closer look at the logic. You might want to hold the index of the letter that was most, instead of comparing with the next letter.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand, could you fix my code?

Comment: Hopefully, I have pointed you in the right direction - please take a litle time to try to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a lot of problems. And a good bit of traps.

```c
scanf("%s", str);
```

What if the input is longer than `str` can hold?

```c
count=strlen(str);
```

This is a waste of cpu cycles. You don't need the length of a string to loop through it, you can simply check if the current element of the string is a `\0`

```c
for(i=0; i<count; i++) {
    h[str[i]-97]++;
}
```

This is problematic, what if the input contained some other character than lower case characters, this could easily cause out of bounds reading.

```c
for(j=0; j<25; j++) {
    if(h[j]<h[j+1]) {
        tmp=j+1;
    }
}
```

Firstly, this loop stops before `25`, but it should stop before `26`

Secondly, this definitely does not do what you think it does.

If you want to print the most frequent lower case character from in your input, this is how the flow should look like-

- Take the string input and store it into a char array, make sure it can actually hold it
- Declare a variable to keep track of the number of occurrences for each lowercase alphabet
- Loop through the input string

  - Check if the current element is lowercase - if it is, add to the counter - if it isn't, do nothing
- Loop through the occurrences record, check if the current occurrence is higher than the highest record (which is set to 0 before the loop) - if it higher, change the highest record to it and store the character - if it isn't, move on
- Print the resulting character

This is how that'd look like in C-

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ALPHABET_COUNT 26
#define MAX_LEN 100

int main()
{
    char str[MAX_LEN];
    int occurrences[ALPHABET_COUNT] = { 0 };
    if (!fgets(str, MAX_LEN, stdin))
    {
        // Something went wrong, error handling here
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (islower(str[i]))
        {
            occurrences[str[i] - 'a']++;
        }
    }
    int highest_occurrence = 0;
    char highest_occurring_char;
    for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_COUNT; i++)
    {
        if (occurrences [i] > highest_occurrence)
        {
            highest_occurrence = occurrences[i];
            // Convert the current index to its corresponding lowercase alphabet
            highest_occurring_char = (char) (i + 'a');
        }
    }
    printf("Highest occurring character: %c\n", highest_occurring_char);
}
```

Comment: this: `for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)` can be reduced to: `for ( int i = 0; str[i]; i++ )`.  This: `if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')` will not work with character sets where the lower case characters are no contiguous.  Suggest adding: `#include <ctype.h>` then replacing with: `if( islower( str[i] )`

Comment: other than the answer contains a 'magic' number: 100.  Suggest using a `#define` to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name.    For robustness, need to check the returned value from `fgets()`, as the user can mess up an input very easily.